# Как сделать JSON-RPC запрос с клиента

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Сделал небольшой сервер с JSON-RPC и хочу с клиента отправить запрос, немогу найти примеры в нете. Есть куча либ но нету чистого запроса.

Comment: Сначала напиши код клиента.

Comment: html с формой для ввода логина и пароля https://github.com/IhorBondartsov/OLX_Parser/tree/master/website/view

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете jquery, то лучше отправлять json rpc запросы с помощью `$.ajax()`. Вот например

```
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/testJsonUrl",
    dataType:"json",            
    data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0', method:'someMethod', id:'jsonrpc'}),  
    contentType: "application/json-rpc; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(response) {
      var result= response.result;  
      ...
    }
  });
```

Comment: Ну я вот хотел бы написать на чистом JS, кое что вроде нашел но оно не работает!(

Comment: На чем у вас сервер?

Comment: Golang в репе это userMS

Comment: Ну и на нем же написан сервер  на котором вьюшная часть, пытаюсь сделать запросик с на другой мс

Comment: Еще там проблема с CORS

Comment: Вы определитесь с вопросом - "Как сделать JSON-RPC запрос с клиента"